# Actionscript 3: Else clause on loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, break, for-else

From Python I've been used to that you can use an else-clause that is triggered if a loop has not been terminated by a `break`. Apparently this function isn't in ActionScript 3, but is there som kind of workaround?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a boolean variable to keep track of the loop state and then you can check the value of that variable after the loop. For example:

```
// If the loop executes all iterations, this variable will stay false
var bLoopBreak:Boolean = false;

for ( ... )
{
    ...

    if ( some_condition )
    {
        // Break out of loop and set variable
        bLoopBreak = true;
        break;
    }

    ...
}

if ( bLoopBreak )
{
    // for loop has been terminated through a break
}
```